# Complicated mysql statement

Tags: mysql

hi i need to display order details for customer order (orderid, customerid, itemdetails ) 
i have avalible orderID and emali, email is coresponding to customer id in my table and when i try following statement

`select a.*, b.* from customer_order a, order_item b where a.orderID = b.orderID and customerID = 30;`

it works fine however i need to use customer email instead of customerID but customerID is my link between tables so i need to have it in statement. how can i use union or how i can link together corresponding fields in table customerID and email.

my customer table have  customerID, customerName, customerSurname,email

order table have orderID, customerID

and orderItem table have orderID and all items details

please share if you have any ideas

Comment: You say your have three tables, and yet you don't use them in your query.  In addition to learning how to ask intelligible questions, you should learn proper `join` syntax.

Comment: this statement is only to show how result must looks like so the statement shows this what i want however i dont have customerID only email and english is my second language so my question may souds oddly to most of people whos english is their first language

Comment: what exactly do you plan to do when the customer have multiple orders?

Comment: this is part of user account (display order) so when user confim email (which i want to link with customerID so all orders that belongs to that user will be displayed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just join the tables together like this:

```
SELECT
    co.*, oi.*
FROM
customer c
JOIN customer_order co ON c.customerID = co.customerID
JOIN order_item oi ON co.orderID = oi.orderID
WHERE
c.email = [ the email you want ]
```